# Stored procedure temporary tables range across diffrent users and life time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have question regarding temporary tables. I have a stored procedure as shown below. Should I somehow drop my temporary tables somehow or they will be dropped automatically once the stored procedure is finished (if so what would be right place to do so?)

Second question is: if two users fire this stored procedure at the same time, would they share the same temporary tables, or does each user's stored procedure have its own temp table?

P.S If there is something that can be tune up in my stored procedure, let me know besides.

Thanks !

```
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test]
    @Level INT,
    @KatSubkatId INT,   
    @WordId INT,
    @SubsubkatId INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @temp_T_Html_Word_Categories TABLE(Id INT)
    DECLARE @temp_T_Html_WordCat_Phrase TABLE(FK_Phrase_ID INT)

    IF (@Level = 2)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @temp_T_Html_Word_Categories(Id) SELECT Id FROM T_Html_Word_Categories WHERE FK_KatSubkat_ID = @KatSubkatId And FK_Word_ID = @WordId
        END
    ELSE IF (@Level = 3)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @temp_T_Html_Word_Categories(Id) SELECT Id FROM T_Html_Word_Categories WHERE FK_KatSubkat_ID = @KatSubkatId And FK_Word_ID = @WordId And FK_Subsubkat_ID IS NULL;
            INSERT INTO @temp_T_Html_Word_Categories(Id) SELECT Id FROM T_Html_Word_Categories WHERE FK_KatSubkat_ID = @KatSubkatId And FK_Word_ID = @WordId And FK_Subsubkat_ID = @SubsubkatId;
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT null;
            RETURN;
        END

        print 'I am here'

    INSERT INTO @temp_T_Html_Word_Categories(Id) SELECT Id FROM T_Html_Word_Categories WHERE FK_KatSubkat_ID = @KatSubkatId And FK_Word_ID = @WordId

    --DECLARE @v XML = (SELECT * FROM @temp_T_Html_Word_Categories FOR XML AUTO)

    Declare @Id int;
    --it makes no difference what you SELECT in an EXISTS sub-query as it is just syntactical sugar. (ie Nothing is actually selected.) SELECT * or SELECT 1 ...
    WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @temp_T_Html_Word_Categories)        
    BEGIN
        Select Top 1 @Id = Id From @temp_T_Html_Word_Categories;

    INSERT INTO @temp_T_Html_WordCat_Phrase(FK_Phrase_ID) SELECT FK_Phrase_ID FROM T_Html_WordCat_Phrase WHERE FK_Word_Categorie_ID = @Id;
        Delete @temp_T_Html_Word_Categories Where Id = @Id;     
    END;

    --IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM T_Html_Phrase WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT FK_Phrase_ID FROM @temp_T_Html_WordCat_Phrase))
    --  SET @IddD = 1;
    --ELSE
    --  SET @IddD = 0;


    SELECT * FROM T_Html_Phrase WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT FK_Phrase_ID FROM @temp_T_Html_WordCat_Phrase)

    --DECLARE @b XML = (SELECT * FROM T_Html_Phrase FOR XML AUTO)

    Delete @temp_T_Html_WordCat_Phrase;

END
```

Answer (score 2):

I see no temporary tables in your proc code, only table variables. These are local in scope to the proc in which they are declared and will be destroyed automatically when the proc finishes. They are only visible within the proc code.

Separately, local temp tables (`#` prefix) created in a proc are local to the session and will be dropped automatically when the proc completes. These are visible within the proc code as well as other modules called from within the proc.

Comment: # prefix - means also only along stored procedure execution time for this particural user? P.S Is there any temp table to be shred across other users and whats lifetime of it?

Comment: @Arie, yes. Temporary tables with a single `#` prefix are local to the session that created it and cannot be accessed by other sessions. Even when different sessions create tables with the same `#` prefix name, they cannot be accessed by a different session because SQL Server adds a uniqueifier to the name. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql for details.